# How to use a Git repository with multiple projects?

Tags: git, github, version-control, repository

I'm new to Github. Was unable to find a tutorial regarding this.

- I have a repository `core-repository`, which contains core modules of all my projects.
- If I were to make changes in the `core-repository`, it has to affect all its dependent projects.
- These projects are individual repositories, with `core-repository` as part of them.

How to implement this?

```
core-modules/
    module1/
    module2/

project1/
    folder1/
        core-modules/
            module1/
            module2/
```

Note: Please comment before downvoting. As well point towards a valid solution.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use **[submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)** in order to:

- define one "parent" repo per project
- one submodule for the actual project repo (your current "individual repos")
- one submodule for the `core-repository`

That is:

```
parent (one repo)
  core (one repo)
  src (one repo)
    core -> ../core
```

Once cloned, you still need to make a symlink from inside the source project repo to the `core-repo` folder.

If the `core-repo` has new commits, a simple [`git submodule update --remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#git-submodule---remote) inside each parent repo is enough to get those new commits inside the core submodule.

Comment: However, if your language has a package manager (e.g. Gem for Ruby, NPM or Yarn for JavaScript), use that in preference to Git submodules in most cases.

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser Agreed. That will do a better job than relying only on Git.